# How to split items in Checkedlistbox having strings like A+B+C?

Tags: c#, .net, split, checkedlistbox

I have a checkedlistbox in which i am populating items like:

1. Biology+Physics+Chemistry
2. English+Urdu+Islamiyat

and so on. Now when i retrieve the values of selected items by splitting them on the basis of '+' sign, it gives me an output like:

```
                    Biology
                    Physics
                    ChemistryEnglish
                    Urdu
                    Islamiyat
```

Now you can look at the output as all values are right except **ChemistryEnglish** which have got concatenated. What should i be doing so to make this right? **I want the output like this:**

```
                    Biology
                    Physics
                    Chemistry
                    English
                    Urdu
                    Islamiyat
```

**UPDATED**

**MY CODE IS:**

```
                String items = "";
                string SQLString = "";
                if (this.subjects_listbox.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.subjects_listbox.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        items += this.subjects_listbox.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
                    }

                } //
                String[] subNames = items.Split('+');
                foreach (var item in subNames)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item); 
                }
```

**Finally i achieved my goal this by doing this:**

```
                String items = "";
                string SQLString = "";
                if (this.subjects_listbox.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.subjects_listbox.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        items += this.subjects_listbox.CheckedItems[i].ToString() + "+";
                    }

                } //
                String[] subNames = items.Split('+');
                foreach (var item in subNames)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item); 
                }
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: How do you split them, post the code?

Comment: Kindly check my code i have updated my question please!

Comment: `items` is just one string, but you've given two at the start of your question.

Comment: I am concatenating them into one String Sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to split out the items in the CheckedListBox individually before you do what you are doing with items.  Take the following code (assuming myCheckedListBox is the name of your CheckedListBox)

```
var subNameList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in myCheckedListBox.Items)
{
    foreach (string subName in (item.ToString().Split('+'))
    {
        subNameList.Add(subName);
    }
}
```

This will result in you having a list of strings at the end in subNameList.  You may want to use myCheckedListBox.CheckedItems rather than myCheckedListBox.Items depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Your code worked too. I had also tried to make it happen and finally got it. Thanks everybody for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my goal by doing this:

```
                String items = "";
                string SQLString = "";
                if (this.subjects_listbox.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.subjects_listbox.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        items += this.subjects_listbox.CheckedItems[i].ToString() + "+";
                    }

                } 
                String[] subNames = items.Split('+');
                foreach (var item in subNames)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item); 
                }
```